# Add a combo box for custom service in Ambari UI

Tags: apache, hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I'm implementing a custom service that is configured via Ambari UI and I want to add property to specify Authentication tyupe that could be either LDAP or KERBEROS.
In my service-config.xml I have the following lines:

```
<property>
<name>serviceAuthType</name>
<value>KERBEROS</value>
<value-attributes>
  <type>attribute-list</type>
  <entries>
    <entry>
      <value>KERBEROS</value>
      <label>KERBEROS</label>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <value>LDAP</value>
      <label>LDAP</label>
    </entry>
  </entries>
  <selection-cardinality>1</selection-cardinality>
</value-attributes>
```

but I still having it displayed as normal input:
[image: existing stuff]
not combo box or radio button.
I want to see somethinh like Hive has for metastore database selection:

[image: required]

Is it possible to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, your property was not defined correctly. It should be:

```
<property>
 <name>hive.default.fileformat</name>
 <value>TextFile</value>
 <description>Default file format for CREATE TABLE statement.</description>
 <display-name>Default File Format</display-name>
 <value-attributes>
   <type>attribute-list</type>
   <entries>
    <entry>
      <value>ORC</value>
      <label>ORC</label>
      <description>The Optimized Row Columnar (ORC) file format ...</description>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <value>TextFile</value>
      <label>TextFile</label>
      <description>Text file format saves Hive data as normal text.</description>
    </entry>
  </entries>
  <selection-cardinality>1</selection-cardinality>
 </value-attributes>
</property>
```

In addition you will need to ensure that your services is configured with a theme. This requires editing the metainfo.xml for the service.

```
<themes>
        <theme>
          <fileName>theme.json</fileName>
          <default>true</default>
        </theme>
</themes>
```

This is all documented in the [Ambari wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Enhanced+Configs).

Comment: I saw that wiki page but this approach does not work without Ambari Themes Framework.

Comment: The fact that theme definition is required is documented in the wiki as well. Updated the post to make that clear.